# Is this justification to prove this is a continuous function correct?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity, solution-verification

Given the following function:
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{\sin xy}{e^x-y^2}\;,
$$
is the following justification correct?

As **sin** is a continuous function, the **exponential** is a continuous function, the **polynomials** are continuous functions and the **subtraction** of continuous functions are continuous functions, both the numerator and denominator are continuous functions, hence the **quotient** of two continuous functions is a continuous function for all values of its domain.

Comment: No, the denominator has to be different from $0$

Comment: But I said it is continuous for all values of its domain. Wouldn't that suffice?

Comment: You have to say what is its domain then ... I could say "the function is continuous on every point where it is continuous", problem solved :D

Comment: ah, got it, thanks!

Comment: And actually, what about the points where $e^x = y^2$? Perhaps it is possible to extend the function by continuity on these points when $\sin(xy) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratio of 2 continuous functions is continuous in points where denominator is not null. So, in your case, you need $e^x \ne y^2$.

Comment: But I said it is continuous for all values of its domain. Wouldn't that suffice?

Comment: Generally function is defined, when is defined 3 objects: domain, image and graphic=set of pairs. Let me bring example: let' define $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ where $x \ne 0$ and $f(0)=1$. Point "0" is in domain, but $f$ is not continuous in it. In your case, if you exclude from domain $e^x=y^2$, then, of course you are correct.